# jsTree select checkbox independent to hierarchy

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, selection, jstree

I'm using jsTree with checkboxes, and it checks all the parent nodes when selecting a child.

Is there a way to select each node individually regardless to the hierarchy?

Currently:

[image]

Desired:

[image]

Here's my code:

```
$(function () {
 $('#tree').jstree({
  "checkbox": {
   "two_state": true,
   "real_checkboxes": true,
   //this is supposed to fix it but it doesn't
   "override_ui": true
  },
  "plugins": ["themes", "ui", "checkbox"]
 });
 $('#tree').jstree("hide_icons");
 $('#tree').jstree("hide_dots");   
});
```

[Here](http://www.jstree.com/documentation/checkbox) is the documentation.

Comment: `two_state` option works for me. http://jsfiddle.net/bUXgk/

Comment: I tried the code from your fiddle and it doesn't work. what else can I think of?

Comment: Which plugin are you using for loading data? i.e.(html_data / json_data / xml_data) plugin? also are you sure the version i used in fiddle and your version are same?

Comment: I realize this is a inconsistency issue in jsTree. Using your fiddle with my jstree.js [sources](https://github.com/vakata/jstree/tree/master/dist), leads to [different results](http://jsfiddle.net/WHTBw/). Can you help me fix it? I prefer sticking to the alpha version, the pre version is causing me issues in other jsTrees in my website.

Comment: Can you think of anything?

Comment: It seems in the master version the property `two_state` is changed to `three_state`. Can you plug the tree with the option `"three_state": false` in your development?

Comment: @shakib, this is the answer! Please post as one.

Comment: @shakib, and btw, the `"themes":{dots: false, icons: false}` doesn't work either.

Comment: glad it worked out. posted as answer. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the current master version in [GitHub](https://github.com/vakata/jstree) (2.0.0 alpha),

```
$(function () {
    $('#demo1').jstree({
        "checkbox": {
            "three_state": false
        },
        "core": {
            "themes": {
                dots: false,
                icons: false
            }
        },
        "plugins": ["html_data", "themes", "ui", "checkbox"]
    });
});
```

hope this helps.

Comment: You're the man! I see there are [other properties](http://www.jstree.com/documentation/checkbox) missing: `real_checkboxes`, `real_checkboxes_names`, their functionality is essential to me, do you know if they have a replacement?

Comment: Thanks. unfortunately i have not found any indication supporting the mentioned features. I think VERSION 2.0.0-ALPHA is in development stage, the project page states its not production ready.

Comment: How funny. In that very page there are two links, one 'development' the other one 'production' which leads to the master folder.

Comment: Beats me, i think your best bet is with https://github.com/vakata/jstree/tree/v.pre1.0

Answer (score 0):

Using 3.3.8 version of jsTree, yes, instead of using `two_state:true`, use `"three_state": false` in checkbox plugins.
@shakib is right above. For complete and working source code, you can refer https://everyething.com/Example-of-jsTree-to-get-all-checked-nodes#GetAllCheckedNodeWithTriStateDisabled